# How splitting a file in two with regex

Tags: vim

I have a text file containing two or more  types of lines. I would like to separate it into two different files.
I do that with this list of commands :

```
:%g/myregexpforlinetype1/ . w >> file1
:%g/myregexpforlinetype1/d
:w file2
```

But I think it is not optimal.
How could I make this more generic, more robust, more efficient ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact that `:v` matches all lines not matching a search expression combined with the fact that `//` will repeat the previous search:

```
:%g/myregexpforlinetype1/ . w >> file1
:%v// . w >> file2
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution is good for me. Especially as it made ​​me discover a new vim command ":v//".